# How resolve Problem with Parsing Json in MyObject?

Tags: java, json, selenium, gson

Hi i have a big problem with my code. I realize a personal class for serialize and deserialize objects in Json and for this i use GSON but.
This is my class.

```
public class JsonUtil<T> {
private Gson gson=new Gson();

public JsonUtil(){}
public List<T> getJsonsFile(File file) throws IOException{
    List<T> list=null;
    try(Reader reader=new FileReader(file.getPath())) {
         list= gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<Collection<T>>(){}.getType());

        return list;
    }
}
public void writeJsonInFile(File file,List<T> list) throws IOException{
    try(Writer writer=new FileWriter(file.getPath())){
        gson.toJson(list, writer);
    }
}
```

And this is my main

```
public class Prova{
public String id;
public Prova(String a){
    id=a;

}
public static void main(String[] args){
final File file=new File("MyFollowers copia.json");
JsonUtil<Prova> jsonUtil=new JsonUtil<>();
List<Prova> a=null;

try{
    a=jsonUtil.getJsonsFile(file);
}catch (IOException e){}
System.out.println(a.get(0));

}
```

My example of Json

```
[{"id":"alexandra04.___"},{"id":"riky_vicini"},{"id":"martatofanarii"},{"id":"about._mary"}]
```

Now when i run my code i get this output

```
{id=alexandra04.___}
```

I search this problems but i don't understand how to resolve this

I'll want my object List a with all objects Prova and i'll want use this

```
for(Prova prova:a){System.out.println(a.id);}
```

HI I RESOLVED WITH THIS

```
public <T> List<T> getJsonsFile(File file,Class<T> cls) throws IOException{
    List<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
    try(Reader reader=new FileReader(file.getPath())) {
        JsonArray arry=new JsonParser().parse(reader).getAsJsonArray();
        for(JsonElement jsonElement:arry){
            list.add(gson.fromJson(jsonElement,cls));
        }
    return list;
        //return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Looks OK to me. Your list should have 4 members with the first one being alexandra04. You might add a toString() method to your Prova class if you want a different outcome

Comment: I update this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code work perfectly you need to change last instruction in your code because you show in console first element in list

```
 System.out.println(a.get(0)); // change this instruction by this 
 System.out.println(a);   // show result is [{id=alexandra04.___}, {id=riky_vicini}, {id=martatofanarii}, {id=about._mary}]
```

Comment: I want extract only id without [{id=}]